# How to call functions inside a DLL file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, ctypes

I'm currently working on a python project that uses functions from a DLL in C#. I'm trying to use the ctypes module but I'm getting an error:

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

The code that is giving me the problem is this:

```
DLL = ctypes.CDLL("c:\\Users\\Hunter1300FC\\Desktop\\MyDLL\\WeAreDevs_API-cpp.dll")
```

I'm using python 3.8.5 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your DLL file is likely compiled in 32-bit. Either load a 64-bit DLL or try with 32-bit python. You can easily install 32-bit python with miniconda.